# id 1 respawning too fast

Tags: raspbian, boot-issues

I have a really bad problem with my pi, when I'm booting I'm getting the error "Id 1 respawning too fast, disabled for 5 minutes"

I know the error, it's a syntax error in the inittab file, but I don't know how to change it, because the files are readonly on other devices and I can't edit it on my pi, because it doesn't boot :(

Anyone knows something?

Comment: reinstall your device and prevent it from getting the same error again.

Comment: if you have a (non-rPi) Linux computer with an SD card reader, it should be possible to insert the SD card there and edit the files.

Answer (score 1):

OK. This will be a little bit hacky but it is possible to get to a point where you can edit /etc/inittab again. This assumes that you can edit at least the FAT32 partition of the SD card. Add init=/bin/sh to the end of the cmdline.txt file. This will dump you into a straight shell on boot. (You'll need to revert this change later.) Once it boots to the shell, you'll need to mount the root file system read-write so that you can make permanent changes to /etc/inittab. mount -o remount,rw / should work. After that, nano /etc/inittab, fix the syntax errors, halt 0, re-edit cmdline.txt and you should be good to go. Unfortunately I can't test these directions out as I don't have access to a Pi right this moment, but in general they should work.